# Look up objects that aren't the target of any foreign keys using Django ORM

Tags: python, django

I have two models, `Author` and `Book`. I need to get all `Author`s who have no `Books` with Django's ORM. How can I do that?

Here are my models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField()


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books')
```

I am currently doing it with `for` loop, but I would prefer to do it with the ORM:

```
for person in Author.objects.all():
    if person.books.count() == 0:
        "something code"
```

But it need to make update for objects.

I tried this but I just get an empty `QuerySet`:

```
Author.objects.select_related('books').values('id').annotate(books_count=Count('id')).filter(books_count=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.annotate(books_count=Count('id'))
```

Django will count the *`Author`'s* `id`s here. Try

```
.annotate(books_count=Count('books__id'))
```

instead. The double underscore indicates a [query that spans relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to "follow" relationships in lookups, taking care of the SQL `JOIN`s for you automatically, behind the scenes. To span a relationship, just use the field name of related fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get to the field you want.
>
> This example retrieves all `Entry` objects with a `Blog` whose `name` is `'Beatles Blog'`:
>
> ```
> >>> Entry.objects.filter(blog__name='Beatles Blog')
> ```

Comment: Yes, I know about double underscore, but not quite clear, that 'books__id' needed for right query. Ok, thats works! I try to understand it with print('....query'). Thank you!